# incomprehensible behavior of attribute app:elevation

Tags: android

I wonder why such a strange behavior in the app attribute: elevation = "0dp" and how to solve the problem. I use the androidx library. The toolbar is transparent. Shadow remains. When I write an app: elevation = "0dp", the shadow disappears, but the toolbar buttons, including the "back" buttons, stop responding.

I tried to solve it in other ways: `android: elevation = "0dp"`

programmatically set `getSupportActionBar (). setElevation (0);` Does not help.

layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/back_gray">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/iv_like"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/heart_outline"
                        android:visibility="visible"/>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/iv_shared"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/shared"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
 <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
              .....>

                <TextView
                  ........./>

                <TextView
                 ........../>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment.java:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_data, container, false );
    toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    if ( activity != null ) {
        activity.setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
        //  activity.getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled( true );
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled( true );
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( false );

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet instead of `toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener`

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
          getActivity().onBackPressed();
      }
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
```

hope this will solve your problem.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is just because you have used **FrameLayout** as a parent - and also ***removed elevation*** from **AppBarLayout**, and due to this, Your **ScrollView** is overlapping your **AppBarLayout** as it is written below **AppBarLayout**. change your root to something else, for eg.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout">

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```